# Rewrite Rule That Handles URL Strings with One or More Hyphens

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I have a rewrite rule in place that takes requests for a URL string `/site-aboutpage` and rewrites it to `/site/site-aboutpage`. That works well! However I have URL strings with one or two hyphens, and I'm not sure how to handle those. `/site-name/aboutpage`or `/site-name/about-page` should be rewritten to `/site-name/site-name-aboutpage`or `/site-name/site-name-about-page`

Here's a site of URLs I need to create rules for:

```
/biomedical-sciences 
/allied-health
/body-donation-program
```

The above URLs are correct and are the root of their respective sites.

The rewrite rule below changes the URLs to

```
/allied/allied-health
/biomedical/biomedical-sciences
/body/body-donation
```

I figure I'll probably need two rules for the above items. But the short of it is that the root directory URL shouldn't be rewritten, only if there's characters after the last word i.e. while `/allied-health` wouldn't be rewritten, `/allied-health-about` would be rewritten to `/allied-health/allied-health-about`. That make sense?

Here's what I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/body-donation-program
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/allied-health
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/biomedical-sciences
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$1-$2/ [L,R=301]
```

The first three rules are conditionals so that the rewrite rule on the last line doesn't interfere with them.

Comment: If `/body-donation-program` is redirecting to `/body/body-donation` then how come `/allied-health-about would be rewritten to /allied-health/allied-health-about` It is confusing.

Comment: Hey anubhava, thanks for the reply. The thing to note here is that the top level directory is the name for a school or program. `/body-donation-program` and `/allied-health` are both programs. We migrated the site to a CMS. Previously our URL structures were 'flat.' So everything was separated via hyphens. So the old URLs were structured like `/body-donation-program-aboutpage`. Now the URLs are structured like `/body-donation-program/aboutpage` Really we just want to catch old URLs and route them to the appropriate page. Not sure if that helps clarify things or not.

Comment: Still not clear. Is it always true that text before last hyphen makes the directory name and rest of the text is file name?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `/some-program-name/some-page-name` will always be `/some-program-name/some-program-name-some-page-name` or `/some-program/some-page` would be `/some-program/some-program-some-page`

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/body-donation\-program
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/allied\-health
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/biomedical\-sciences
RewriteRule ^([^/].*)\-([^/].*)/?$ /$1/$1\-$2/ [L,R=301]
```

This, `^([^/].+)\-([^/].+)/?$` will match:

Any character except `/` one or more times, `-`, any character except `/` one ore more times, `/` (optional), `end`.

Comment: Hey Manolo,
When I tried this rule `RewriteRule ^([^/].+)\-([^/].+)/?$ /$1/$1-$2/ [L,R=301]` it seemed to cause a large URL request string error. Any thoughts there?

Comment: What is it rewritten in the URL.

Comment: It continued to repeat the primary url over and over if requesting `/osteopathy` that url was repeated and broke the site: `/osteopathy/osteopathy/osteopathy etc.`

Comment: You may need to escape the `-` symbols. Try now.